# Getting line number of json file at which the json validation failed

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) for validating my json.

**I want to show the line number in the json data file where the validation failure occurs.** I want to show the failure messages in the user friendly manner. 
I get the pointer to the json node where the validation failure might have occurred as follows:

```
JsonNode jsondatanode = JsonLoader.fromFile(new File("jsondata.json"));
JsonNode jsonschemanode = JsonLoader.fromFile(new File("jsonschema.json"));

final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
final JsonSchema datastoreschema = factory.getJsonSchema(jsonschemanode);

ProcessingReport report;        
report = datastoreschema.validate(jsondatanode);
```

However the pointer is inconvenient to locate the json object/attribute when the json file contains many nodes of type specified by the pointer.

I got following validation failure message:

```
--- BEGIN MESSAGES ---
error: instance value (12) not found in enum (possible values:["true","false","y","n","yes","no",0,1])
level: "error"
schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/configuration/items/properties/skipHeader"}
instance: {"pointer":"/configuration/0/skipHeader"}
domain: "validation"
keyword: "enum"
value: 12
enum: ["true","false","y","n","yes","no",0,1]
---  END MESSAGES  ---
```

I want to show the custom message for validation failures with the line number in json data file which caused schema validation failure. I know I can access the individual details of validation report as shown in below code.

**I want to show the custom message as follows:**

```
List<ProcessingMessage> messages = Lists.newArrayList((AbstractProcessingReport)report);
JsonNode reportJson = messages.get(0).asJson();
if(reportJson.get("keyword").toString().equals("enum"))
{
    System.out.println("Value "+report.Json.get("value").toString() +"is invalid in " + filepath + " at line " + linenumber); 
}
else if{
    //...
}
//...
```

**What I dont understand is how can I get that `linenumber` variable in above code.**

**Edit**

Now I realize that

```
instance: {"pointer":"/configuration/0/skipHeader"}
```

shows which occurrence of `skipHeader` is into problem and in this case its 0th instance of `skipHeader` inside `configuration`. However I still think its better to get the line number which ran into problem.

Comment: Hi @Mahesha999, were you able to find a solution? I have the exact same need.

Comment: nope as much as I remember, I had deviced some quirky way to reading json file recursively to determine where the validation might have failed...but not remembering it exactly...

Answer (score 0):

(library author here)

While it can be done (I have somewhere an implementation of `JsonParser` which does just that) the problem is that the line/column information will most of the time be irrelevant.

In order to save bandwidth, most of the time, JSON sent over the wire will always be on a single line, therefore the problem will remain that you would get, say, "line 1, column 202" without getting any the smarter.

I'll probably do this anyway for the next major version but for 2.2.x it is too late...

Comment: Yep thanks for response, we already talked on github on this, anyways will try that too